# Passing bound column value into razor function for MVC Kendo UI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, grid

I need to use bound column value inside razor function which is used inside ClientTemplate of Kendo UI MVC grid. Like 'AnyColumnValue' parameter below:

```
.ClientTemplate(@KendoHtmlFuncs.RequestingDeleteWithConfirmationLink(itemNameL, AnyColumnValue));
```

Full example is below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DisplayOfGroupCompanyVm>()
        .Name(itemNameL + "-definitions-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DateCreated).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(DateCreated,'yyyy-MM-dd')#"); //.Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CreateStatus);

        columns.Template(@<text></text>)
                   .Width(100)
                   .ClientTemplate(@KendoHtmlFuncs.GetModalForRequestingEditLink(itemNameL));
        columns.Template(@<text></text>)
                .Width(100)
                .ClientTemplate(@KendoHtmlFuncs.RequestingDeleteWithConfirmationLink(itemNameL, AnyColumnValue));
        })
```

Comment: What is AnyColumnValue? The actual value of a column from the dataSource bound to the grid?  If so, you can't do what you are trying to do as KendoHtmlFuncs.RequestingDeleteWithConfirmationLink() is a server-side function(executes on server during cshtml rendering) but AnyColumnValue does not have a value until the grid is bound to the dataSource on the client.  It looks like you would have to make RequestingDeleteWithConfirmationLink() a client-side function...You can't *execute* server code in a ClientTemplate.

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen Thanks, it is right. Beside this, is there a workaround to use column value as a parameter of razor function?

Comment: I don't think so as the values of the column do not exist on the server(where the razor function is executed).  You *can* use the actual column value in the ClientTemplate as the ClientTemplate is executed on the client when the row is rendered, you just can't call the Razor function as it has already been executed on the server to generate the HTML for the view that is then returned to the client.  See http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#clienttemplate or provide the implementation of the function and the column you are passing and I will try to write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of some digging after comments of @TheDreadPirateStephen, (thanks to him) I changed my way for a workaround. The main point in his comment is 'You can't execute server code in a ClientTemplate'. Then a workaround as below is feasible to me.

```
.ClientTemplate(@KendoHtmlFuncs.RequestingDeleteWithConfirmationLink(itemNameL));
```

I gave up to use AnyColumnValue (The actual value of a column from the dataSource bound to the grid) inside html razor function. Instead of this, I've used it inside returned script by razor function. In the razor function seen below, **HasPermissionForRequestingDelete** variable corresponds to **AnyColumnValue** and it is belong to model bound to grid.

```
public static string RequestingDeleteWithConfirmationLink(string itemNameL)
    {
        string linkFormat = @"<a {0} class='k-button'>
                                        <i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Request For Delete
                              </a>";

        string conditionalPart = @"#if(HasPermissionForRequestingDelete){#
                                        onclick='" + itemNameL + @"_DefinitionsFunc.requestingDelete(this, #= Id #)'
                                   #}else{#
                                       disabled='disabled'
                                   #}#";

        return string.Format(linkFormat, conditionalPart);
    }
```